# Infuser is not defined

Tags: templates, knockout.js

I am trying to use Knockout external template plugin.  Firefox stops in my util.js on this line: infuser.defaults.templateUrl = "/CAS/templates";

It complains that infuser is undefined.  If I simply press continue in Firebug, the view loads and loads the template just fine.  If I comment that line out, the template does not load and I get a file not found error.  So that setting is working despite infuser is not defined.  Here is the order stuff gets loaded.

```
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/external/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/external/jquery-ui-1-10.2.js",
            "~/Scripts/external/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/external/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
            "~/Scripts/external/knockout-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/external/koExternalTemplateEngine_all.js",
            "~/Scripts/local/utils.js",
            "~/Scripts/external/knockout.mapping-latest.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/local").Include(
        "~/Scripts/local/ajaxservice.js",
        "~/Scripts/local/DMS.CAS.Dataservice.js",
        "~/Scripts/local/DMS.CAS.ViewModel.js",
        "~/Scripts/local/DMS.Models.js"));
```

Here is binding in the view:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'HelloWorld'}"></div>
```

My jQuery version is 2.0.3, KO version is 2.3.0, and the KO External Template plugin was installed via nuGet 1 day ago.  I have pursued this as problem with the order script files being loaded in the wrong order.  But, that does not seem to be the case.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put **infuser.js** into **Knockout** bundle before **koExternalTemplateEngine_all.js**:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
        "~/Scripts/external/knockout-{version}.js",
        "~/Scripts/external/infuser.js",
        "~/Scripts/external/koExternalTemplateEngine_all.js",
        "~/Scripts/local/utils.js",
        "~/Scripts/external/knockout.mapping-latest.js"));
```